# Java Cipher IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: java, exception, encryption, client-server

I just had the "great" idea to encrypt the send/received data from my client and server. But now I get an `IllegalBlockSizeException (Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher)` every time I call `cipher.doFinal()`.

My Code:

I created a singleton class called `SecurityHandler` with `SecretKeySpec keyspec`, `Cipher cipher` and `String securitykey` as private variables, which are initialized in the constructor:

```
private SecurityHandler()
{
    securitykey = "adnanyc83z43h1jbncxgsdfgs2134y";  // Example key

    try
    {
        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOf(securitykey.getBytes("UTF-8"), 16), "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        Logger.log("CipherInitializationException (" + e.getMessage() + ")", e);
    }
}
```

My method to get the `AlgorithmParameterSpec`:

```
public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV()
{
    final byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
    return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
}
```

And my enrypt/decrypt methods:

```
public String encrypt(final String text)
{
    try
    {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, getIV());

        final byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));  // Exception thrown here by doFinal()
        return Base64.encode(encrypted);
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        Logger.log("StringEncryptionException (" + e.getMessage() + ")", e);
    }

    return text;
}

public String decrypt(final String text)
{
    try
    {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, getIV());

        final byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(text);
        final byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(decoded);  // Exception thrown here by doFinal()

        return new String(decrypted);
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        Logger.log("StringDecryptionException (" + e.getMessage() + ")", e);
    }

    return text;
}
```

**SOLVED**

I created a method which makes the array length to a multiple of 16:

```
public static byte[] getBytesM16(final String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    final byte[] bytes = text.getBytes("UTF-8");

    if (bytes.length % 16 == 0)
    {
        return bytes;
    }

    return Arrays.copyOf(bytes, bytes.length + (16 - (bytes.length % 16)));
}

public static byte[] getBytesM16(final byte[] bytes)
{
    if (bytes.length % 16 == 0)
    {
        return bytes;
    }

    return Arrays.copyOf(bytes, bytes.length + (16 - (bytes.length % 16)));
}

public String encrypt(final String text)
{
    try
    {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, getIV());

        final byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(StringHandler.getBytesM16(text));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        Logger.log("StringEncryptionException (" + e.getMessage() + ")", e);
    }

    return text;
}

public String decrypt(final String text)
{
    try
    {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, getIV());

        final byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(text);
        final byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(StringHandler.getBytesM16(decoded));

        return new String(decrypted);
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        Logger.log("StringDecryptionException (" + e.getMessage() + ")", e);
    }

    return text;
}
```

After that I had the issue that the first 16 bytes where not correctly decrypted, because the server creates his own random `IVKey` at startup. To fix that I made sure the server and clients `IVKey`'s are the same, by sending the key as a non-encrypted packet, right when a new client tries to connect.

Comment: As the error implies, the length of your text must be a multiple of 16 with the cipher you are using.

Comment: How many bytes is text.getBytes("UTF-8")? Is that number a multiple of 16?

Comment: text is the String received from the socket. And if I fill the array with zeros so that the length is a multiple of 16, the decryption doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Doesn't work, or contains those 0s?

Comment: Doesn't work, the text is like still encrypted.

Comment: Ok. I'm not an expert on this stuff, so I don't know offhand what may be tripping you up. But the exception you've posted suggests a clear answer, so if you don't think you need to pad the input, you should explain why; and if your real problem if that you can't get the padding to work on decryption, you should ask that.

Comment: I found a solution and edited the post. As you guys said I re-implemented the methods which make sure that the arraylength is a multiple of 16. After that I fixed the mentioned bug where some bytes where like "still encrypted".

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The `PKCS5PADDING` method (it's really PKCS7 padding) does all the padding out to a multiple of the block length for you. Your input is guaranteed by the padding method to be a multiple of 16. Your problem is somewhere else, probably in the protocol you are using to send data between peers.